# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport": for shopify_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, shopify

I am trying to set up an development envoriment to build a Shopify app. I am using Ruby on Rails, Heroku, Postgre, git to make this hopefully easy. when I add the gem shipify_app to the Gemfile I get an activesupport error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
```

In Gemfile:
    shopify_app (= 7.2.6) was resolved to 7.2.6, which depends on
      shopify_api (>= 4.2.2) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
        activeresource was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
          activesupport (= 2.0.1)

```
jbuilder (~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.6.3, which depends on
  activesupport (< 5.2, >= 3.0.0)

rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2)

rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2)

rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2)

rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2)

rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2)

rails (~> 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2)
```

I am new to Ruby on rails and setting up my environment.

This is my Gemfile maybe there is something I messed up. Works just fine if I remove the gem shopify_app

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'shopify_app', '>= 6.1.1'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Gemfile by this command.

```
bundle update
```

Similar solotions is specified here [Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport" and "railties"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795885/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-activesupport-and-railties?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Ends up with errors. I even installed a new installer.

Comment: can you please post stack trace?

Comment: I have not been able to figure out how to get a stack trace.

Comment: Post the content of your terminal where you run rails commands and getting this error.